# Html issue code doing ajax using select2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2

After selecting an option, I use an `ajax` call to update the other `select_tag` but is generating the html code wrong (on id and values).

Tables:

```
|departaments|
  |id|  |name|
   1     dep1
   2     dep2
|provinces|
  |id|  |name| |departament_id|
    1    pr1      1
    2    pr2      1
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @client= Client.new
end

def province_update
  @provinces = Province.where(departament_id: params[:departament_id])
end
```

View **new.html.erb**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".search_select").select2();
  });
</script>
<script>
 $(function() {
   $('#departament_id').on('change', function() {
    $.get("province_update", {
      departament_id: $('#departament_id').val()
    }, function(e) {
       if (e)
       $("#province_id").select2().html(e);
   })
 });
});

</script>

Departament: <%= select_tag :departament_id,options_from_collection_for_select(@departaments, 'id', 'name') %>
Province: <%= select_tag :province_id) %>
```

Javascript **province_update.rjs**

```
$("#province_id").html('<%= j render partial: "provinces_result" %>')
```

Partial **_provinces_result.erb**

```
<%= select_tag :province_id,options_from_collection_for_select(@provinces, 'id', 'name')
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/clients/province_update?departament_id=6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-22 17:03:55 -0500
  Processing by ClientsController#province_update as */*
  Parameters: {"departament_id"=>"6"}
   Province Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `provinces`.`departament_id` = 6  ORDER BY name ASC
   Rendered _provinces_result.erb (2.3ms)
   Rendered client_management/clients/province_update.js.erb (9.1ms)
   Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 12.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Output:

```
<select name="province_id" id="province_id" class="select2-offscreen" title="" tabindex="-1">$("#province").html(' \n\nProvince&lt;\/label&gt; 
   <option value="\&quot;105\&quot;">pr1&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option>
   <option value="\&quot;108\&quot;">pr2&lt;\/option&gt;&lt;\/select&gt;\n')
   $("#district").html('\nDistrito&lt;\/label&gt; </option>
   <option value="\&quot;\&quot;">Select&lt;\/option&gt;&lt;\/select&gt;\n')</option>
</select>
```

I tried this code, but I'm still having the html issue:

```
 $("#province_bill").append('<%= j render partial: "provinces_bill_result" %>')
```

If I change this code, the dropdown won't update:

```
 $("#province_id").select2();
```

I tried this code on the controller, but it is not updating the dropdown:

```
def province_update
  @provinces = Province.where(departament_id: params[:departament_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @provinces }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential problems:

1. The id of your `select_tag` seems to be `#province_id` and not `#province` (as you have in your `.rjs` file). This will mean that the partial is rendered (as you see in your logs) to the `.rjs` file, but then that code isn't used as there isn't a `#province` element in your html.
2. If the new `select_tag` is correctly rendered to the html, `select2` doesn't automatically know to update. You would need to tell it to by saying `$("#province_id").select2();` in your `.rjs` after the first line. This *might* cause two forms to render, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ryan sorry about #province_id i edited the post according the correct code and still show html error.